# Issue with stat_bin(boundary) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `geom_bar` with stat_bin to create a histogram that shows the number of events at various dates (the binwidth is adjustable by the user, via shiny). Before I inserted a boundary variable into stat_bin, the graph looked as it was supposed to, but the last bin often extended past the current date, which looked a bit confusing. I therefore used the boundary variable to make the last bin end at the current date, at which point the graph began to generate a lot of grey bars. Why is this happening? I have included my code, and a picture of a graph with the grey bars.

I used the following code to generate the following plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = df$date) +
  geom_bar() + stat_bin(color = "white", boundary = (Sys.Date() - bin_width), binwidth = bin_width, aes(fill = df$groups)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(start_date, Sys.Date())) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Date", y="", fill="Groups")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without the data, but try taking out the `geom_bar()`. `stat_bin()` will make a geom automatically. I think you are drawing two sets of bars - one from `geom_bar()` and one from `stat_bin()`. When you shift the bars from `stat_bin()`, the second set is visible.

Comment: That was exactly right. I feel pretty silly... thanks a lot!